# Not all map elements changing classname

Tags: reactjs, map-function

I am using react & wanting to update the className of my map elements after an option has been clicked.

The process works if you chose the second element onwards on the array, however when you select the first element in the array the className only updates for this first element. I would like all the elements to update their className when something is selected.

Any help would be great.

```
  const changeHandler = (element) => {
    setSelected(element.target.value);
    const id = element.target.id;
    const class_d = element.target.className;
    let selectedTag = element ? parseInt(element.target.id, 10) : null;
    setClickedItem(selectedTag);
    setResults([...results, { selectedTag}]);
    const selected = data.options[id];
    onAnswerUpdate(prevState => [...prevState, { q: data.question, id: data.id, a: selected }]);
    if ((data.options[id] === data.answer)){
      updateIndicator("correct");
      setCorrectAnswers(correctAnswers + 1);
      setResponse("Correct answer! " + data.answerShow);
      console.log(response);
    } else {
      updateIndicator("wrong");
      setResponse("Wrong answer " + data.answerShow);
      console.log(response);
    }
    if(error) {
      setError('');
    }
  }

  return(
          <div className = "quiz-box custom-box" >
          <div className = "question-number" >
          <span > Question {questionCounter+ 1} of < /span> {numberOfQuestions} </div>
                <div className="question-text">
                {data.question}
                </div>
                <img src={randomImages[data.img]} />
          <div className="option-container ">
              {shuffleanswers.map((option, index) => (
          <div id={index} value={option}
           className={(index === clickedItem) & (data.options[index] === data.answer) ? "option correct" :
           (index === clickedItem) & (data.options[index] !== data.answer) ? "option wrong":
           (clickedItem) ? "option already-answered":
           "option"}
          onClick={changeHandler} key={index}
            > {option}
          </div>
        ))}
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using too many `setState`. That is not error. What I think best is using one `setState`. A simple. Calculate answer is correct or not in function. Then, update state. If this is not exact thing you want, I hope this might give you new idea about how to handle mapping and changing className.

```
function Main() {
  return (
    <div>
      {shuffleanswers.map((item,index)=> <Item key={index} option={item} />)}
    </div>
  )
}

function Item({option}){
  const [isCorrectAnswer,setCorrectAnswer] = useState(null);

const changeHandler = (e)=> {
  // Calculate here is this a correct answer or not


  setState(true or false);
}

return (
  <div className={"option " + isCorrectAnswer !== null && isCorrectAnswer ? " correct" : "wrong"}  onClick={changeHandler}>
    {option}
  </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it still didn't work. When selecting the first element no className updates now.

Comment: can you show your changeHandler and more codes?

Comment: Yes, just updated with changeHandler. I am not sure if I should try to use a setState?

Comment: Come one, provide your states too.